# Where is actual work done - app server or DB server?

Tags: ssis

I am executing SSIS packages from an application server that is different than the database server.  This package will be reading and writing files.  Is it better to have the potentially large input files on the DB server or the application server where the package is executed?  I'm not clear on where the actual "work" takes place when I execute a package on a server other than the database server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Integration Services server is where the actual execution is done.  Generally that means "the DB server" but it doesn't always have to be the same server that the houses the DB you are reading from/writing to.

Comment: So with that in mind, the most efficient location for files would be on the app server itself (where integration services are installed), not on the DB server.  the reason I am posing these questions is because there is some debate in my group as to where incoming data files should be located. My approach has been to let the DB server handle database related activities only and have file storage on the server where the work is done, leaving the DB server uncluttered and reducing the network congestion from handling large files.

Comment: Thanks Daniel for your feedback

Answer (score 0):

"This package will be reading and writing files."

isnt that one of the specialities of a database server? ;)